# How to make bitbake to generate .deb packages

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Bitbake by default generates .rpm files,
But unfortunately .rpm files do not work on debian or ubuntu systems.
How to make bitbake to generate .deb files directly?

Answer (score 7):

First, you can't assume that you'll be able to use your bitbake:ed deb-packages in your regular Debian or Ubuntu system anyway.

Now, the Poky reference distribution (of the Yocto Project), which is what I assume you're using (due to your yocto tag), do default to rpm.

Set `PACKAGE_CLASSES` in `conf/local.conf` or preferably, in your own distro config to:

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"
```

This will configure your build to use deb-packages. (The other options are `package_ipk` or `package_rpm`.